# $F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ vs. $F[x]/\langle g(x)\rangle$ when $\deg f(x)<\deg g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $f(x),~g(x)\in F[x]$ be irreducible and $\deg f(x)<\deg g(x)$. Then is $F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ strictly contained in $F[x]/\langle g(x)\rangle$? For example, does $\Bbb R\subsetneq \Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle\subsetneq \Bbb R[x]/\langle x^4+1\rangle\subsetneq \Bbb R[x]/\langle x^6+1\rangle\subsetneq\cdots\cdots\subsetneq \Bbb R[x]/\langle x^{2k}+1\rangle$?

Comment: Rather than injective (inclusion) maps going one way, it would be more natural to look at surjective (quotient) maps going the other way. Specifically, if $g(x)\in (f(x))$, then there is actually a canonical map $F[x]/(g(x))\to F/(f(x))$.

Comment: Also, your example polynomials aren't irreducible. $x^4 + 1 =  (x^2-\sqrt2x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2+1)$ and $x^6 + 1 = (x^4-x^2+1)(x^2+1)$.

Comment: I think this is only true if $f$ is linear, if we take "contained in" to mean can be embedded in. For example consider $X^2+1$ and $X^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't have very many finite-degree field extensions (there's only one nontrivial one).